# how to access parents scope from ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass the value of $scope.correct into the checkAnswer function but it keeps coming up undefined. ng-click only seems to understand it's own scope. What am I doing wrong?

```
angular.module('Tutorials', ['functions']).controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element){
    $scope.verbs = conjugate(conjugationsets[tutorial_number][questionnum]);
    $scope.correct = $scope.verbs.conjugations[0].text; 
    $scope.randomizeAnswers = function () {

      fisherYates($scope.verbs.conjugations);
    }();

    $scope.checkAnswer = function (answer, correct){
        checkanswer($scope, answer, correct);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `$scope.$parent` to access the parent scope.

Comment: you legend, I should have posted on here about 2 hours ago!

Comment: Can you create a demo of the problem at http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rs4BwMMnKqfC7MIsWB2Q

Comment: sorry, make that http://plnkr.co/edit/Rs4BwMMnKqfC7MIsWB2Q?p=preview

Comment: You should avoid explicitly calling the parent scope with scope.$parent. It makes your code brittle as it will break silently if you add another scope in between.

Comment: Your `$scope.checkAnswer` should be `$scope.checkAnswer = function (answer){`. The `$scope` will be available in the function through `closure`

Comment: Anders, I need to compare the answer that was clicked on (and thus triggered the click and controls scope) to the correct answer which also exists within the same object and has a correct property of "correct". I'm having trouble understanding scope in Angular.

Comment: ok finally I got it working thanks guys, sorry about the noob question but this is the forst MVC framework I've ever used and its taking a whil eto get out of the jQuery mindset!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$parent` to access the parent scope.

```
$scope.checkAnswer = function (answer){
    checkanswer($scope, answer, $scope.$parent.correct);
}
```

Note: I haven't gone through the complete problem to see whether there is an better way to solve the problem